# Force Enable JavaScript in Chrome Incognito

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, google-chrome, google-chrome-flags

Is it possible to force a JavaScript to run using code (c#) in Chrome Incognito?

Cause when I tried to run certain JS in normal Chrome, it works normally. But once I switch to Chrome Incognito, the JavaScript is no longer working.

*Note: I **do not** want to make changes to settings in Chrome

Comment: no longer working in what way? Error in the console? Doesn't even load into the page? something else? as for forcing it in `C#` ... `C#` is server side, so you can't control a browser from server side

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the browser from the server side, but you may do that in the client's side with the JavaScript function **windows.create()**, it accepts an optional incognito parameter, see [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/create#Parameters).

Example: `windows.create({"url": url, "incognito": true});`